# Background Image is not responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, elementor

I'm new here. We are in the process of creating the correct format for the heading. The site is based on WordPress with the builder Elementor. In the container itself we have added the image as .svg. Unfortunately we can't get it to be responsive. Either the red background does not go over the font, or the font itself breaks unfavorably. Is there a suitable solution for this? For example, to store an adapted background image for the different end devices? Or CSS?

Here is the stagings-site: https://staging.renofloor.de/ueber-uns__trashed/karriere/kooperationspartner/
Here is the Background not responsive on some mobile devices.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daDQU.png)
I hope I can ask such a question here.
If so, I look forward to your messages :)

The red background image should be responsive with the included text on the end devices. (Format is .svg)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to show all relevant information here, in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately an svg won't allow you to achieve your goal which, I assume, is to make it look as though you had done a paint stroke and then added text over the top of the stroke and for that to be the case regardless of the height / width of the heading element. As an svg image is vector based it will maintain its proportions regardless of its size meaning it is not really suitable for your use case.

As with most things, there are numerous ways to achieve your goal however the simplest is for you to change the image format and the `background-size` property. A png or a jpg file will allow you to stretch the image to sizes other than its natural aspect ratio which is what you trying to achieve. Bear in mind that stretching images may cause the quality to be below optimal.